# What are the CRUD Commands that have to be run in Tinker with Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, crud, tinker, laravel-8

When I run the known tinder CRUD Commands in Laravel 8, they aren't working

What I ran was the Create and Find commands

```
$user = new App\User;
```

```
App\User::all();
```

But they aren't working, I knew that in Laravel 8, the Model file is in this path App\Models\ 'File', and I tried to modify the creating code from `$user = new App\User;` to `$user = new App\Models\User;`
But also this doesn't work and the error I get is

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'App/Models/User' not found in Psy Shell code on line 1
```

So generaty what are the changes to tinker in Laravel 8

Note: I also tried to clear the cache and clear the composer and it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: the `User` model is `App\Models\User` in a fresh Laravel 8 install ... so `new App\Models\User;`

Comment: What error do you get when you run `$user = new App\Models\User;`?

Comment: This One
` PHP Fatal error:  Class 'App/Models/User' not found in Psy Shell code on line 1  `

Comment: Check the files and see where is the User.php file. once you find it, make sure the declared namespace at the start of the file is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel 8, you should do it this way:

```
$user = new \App\Models\User;
$users = \App\Models\User::all();
```

or above the controller class declaration, do

```
use App\Models\User;
```

then in the method, you can do

```
$user = new User;
$users = User::all();
```

Comment: Thank you, the point that was missing with me is the `use App\Models\User;` in the controller class declaration.